# Prevent iOS app to terminate or relaunch when running on backgroud for long time

Tags: ios, background-process, core-bluetooth

I've developed an iOS app that connects to a BLE peripheral and retrieves heart rate data of one person during the night.

The app runs on the foreground and also on background using Bluetooth accessories background mode.

It receives heart rate data every second and appends it into a file, in order to save a report for the whole night.

The app is working fine in some devices (it writes data during the whole night), but in other devices (tested an iPhone 5s) it relaunches automatically every 1.5 or 2 hours. I found that sometimes iOS kills background apps due to memory pressure, so I made some memory tests with the profiler, but the app only consumes 8MB, and it never gets more than that, so there is no memory issue.

It is really important for me to prevent the app suspending, so I can detect any possible anomaly on the heart rate and trigger an alert.

Any clue on this?

Comment: I'm afraid your users won't like the energy usage of an app that writes data to file every second continuously when it's in background.

Comment: When running in the background you need to just accept that your app may be terminated.  It would be better to ensure your app can retrieve all heart rate samples when it reconnects rather than relying on a constant connection.

Comment: Energy usage is not a problem, testing the whole night it only drains about 20% of the battery on an iPhone6.

Comment: The main problem of the app being terminated and re-launched is that it is not happening at the same moment, sometimes iOS terminates the app and launch it again 30 minutes later, so I can measure what happened to that person within this period.

Comment: If the peripheral doesn't store heart rate data while you aren't connected then there probably isn't much you can do